# Hauser's Mission

Tags: movie, total-recall

If Hauser's memory was wiped and he was never supposed to go to Rekall, what was his mission supposed to be? It seems that if not for him going to Rekall without anyone knowing he would have just live out a pretend life indefinitely.

Comment: Interesting name "Hauser" -- Curt Siodmak wrote Hauser's Memory which was a story about transferring one man's memories into the brain of another.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the 1990 film, Cohaagen and Hauser came up with a plan that was secret from even Richter. Since that plan was to infiltrate the Mars resistance, then the trip to Rekall must have been part of that plan, too. It's only Richter (and his associates) that believe it to have been an accident.

As Robotnik points out, Cohaagen does complain that things did not go entirely as planned:

> "Perfect, my ass! You pop your memory cap before we can activate you. Richter goes hog-wild screwing up everything that I spent a year planning. Frankly... I'm amazed it worked!" - [From IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100802/quotes?qt=qt0480595)

That doesn't discount that a trip to Rekall was on the cards - just that the timing was wrong.

Of course, there's the other interpretation:

> Everything after the trip to Rekall is an implanted memory, and Quaid never actually left for Mars

Comment: I'd like to add - when Cohaagen was explaining Hauser's mission to Quaid, he said something along the lines of "You jumped the gun, set yourself off before everything was in place - frankly I'm surprised the plan worked at all!"
Which means that whilst their WAS a plan, Quaid inadvertently tripped it too early - their might have been another catalyst planned OTHER than a trip to Recall

Comment: forgot that part of the conversation - it's been a while since I saw the film

Comment: Just found the exact quote: "Perfect, my ass! You pop your memory cap before we can activate you. Richter goes hog-wild screwing up everything that I spent a year planning. Frankly... I'm amazed it worked!" [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100802/quotes?qt=qt0480595)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend reading the short story the movie was based upon: "*We can remember it for you wholesale*" by Philip K. Dick. In it, he was a government assassin.

The short story differs from the movie and has a wonderful twist in the ending. To say anything more would spoil the surprise. If you intend to read it, please don't read any plot spoilers (avoid Wikipedia!) because it will spoil the surprise.